# Can not add package Atom to Julia in command line

Tags: package, julia

I have Julia version 1.5.3 on a Windows machine. When I try to add Atom package, I get the following error:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add Atom
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Atom [c52e3926]:
 Atom [c52e3926] log:
 ├─Atom [c52e3926] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
```

Here is the output of status.

```
(@v1.5) pkg> status
Status `C:\Users\USER\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.8.4
```

I tried removing and adding Juno again. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted .julia folder in Users/USER and it worked. When I restarted Julia from the command line, it created the folder again.

Comment: The other way to solve this is to delete the registry and add it again, i.e. `]registry rm General` and `]registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General`.